# Mixed C++/CLI overloading

Tags: c++-cli, overload-resolution

Is this a proper restriction on overloading behavior. I can't figure out how to replicate a similar issue in pure C++ to compare behavior.

C++/CLI code:

```
class A {};

List<int>^ g(A &) {
    return gcnew List<int>();
}

template<typename T>
List<T>^ g(T &) {
    return gcnew List<T>();
}

void f() {
    g(A()); // compiler error C3235
}
```

Generates:

> error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'A', it must be a
>   value type or a handle to a reference type

The problem appears to be from the return values. It's requiring that the templated g() has a valid definition even though the non-templated g() overload should (shouldn't it?) be selected.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug, a violation of SFINAE.

Comment: Oh yeah SFINAE, that pretty much seals it. I've only been using c++/cli for a few days and I've already found 2 compiler bugs.

Comment: You'll find more, don't worry :)